# Can Crizalk 250mg cause extreme forgetfulness?

Tags: medications, side-effects, cancer

For an ALK positive (anaplastic lymphoma kinase) lung cancer, is extreme forgetfulness or any other memory related issues a recognised adverse side effect of treatment with Crizotinib?

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records.

Answer (score 2):

Crizotinib is an oral receptor tyrosine kinase inhibitor indicated for the treatment of patients with advanced or metastatic non-small cell lung cancer.  The [common side effects](https://www.rxlist.com/xalkori-side-effects-drug-center.htm) do not include forgetfulness.  If one experiences memory issues, then one should look for another cause such as the non-small cell lung cancer itself, or, [paraneoplastic manifestations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4127595/), as well as simply depression.